# String2array regex

Tags: php, regex

Can some one explain me what is going on in these 3 functions please?

```
public function normalizeTags($attribute,$params)
{
    $this->tag=Tag::array2string(array_unique(Tag::string2array($this->tag)));
}

public static function string2array($tags)
{
    return preg_split('/\s*,\s*/',trim($tags),-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

public static function array2string($tags)
{
    return implode(', ',$tags);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting an array of tags, filtering duplicate records and returning it to string.

- Splitting an array of tags: using regular expression like "string,
  string"
- filtering: [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
- returning it to string: [implode](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Thank you , one more thing what means the Tag::string2array. Or what ever what does the :: mean?

Comment: it is a static method of Tag class (or model).  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php